# Most efficient way to migrate a MySQL column from a VARCHAR to a foreign key in another table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a few huge (10s of millions of rows in 1 table) legacy tables that have a few columns I should *definitely* have set up to be foreign keys when I created them, but without a time machine, I have to migrate them.

What's in these columns is like a short "key" for something else.  A real example of one of these new tables would be:

```
+----+-----+---------+
| id | key |  name   |
+----+-----+---------+
|  1 | bf  | BetFair |
|  2 | bd  | BetDaq  |
+----+-----+---------+
```

And a current row, in the current table has something like,

`.
(bet_id=1234, odds=2.1, source='bf')
(bet_id=1235, odds=2.15, source='bd')
 .`

And what I want the eventual outcome to be,

`.
(bet_id=1234, odds=2.1, source_id=1)
(bet_id=1235, odds=2.15, source_id=2)
 .`

I know how to do this in multiple steps, create the new tables, add all  the data from the source tables to the new tables with `GROUP BY` / `DISTINCT`, and eventually setting the new foreign key id columns with commands like,

`UPDATE BetsTable SET source_id=1 WHERE source='bf'`,

I'm just wondering if there's more of a "one-shot", efficient `SQL` command to update the entire table in one step, rather than multiple.

Comment: "one step" is not always "most efficient".

Comment: I didn't say it was.  I'm asking for both, and if it's possible.

Comment: Well.. You can't change the data and the schema with one statement.

Comment: Again, that's not what I'm asking exactly, either. I've said that I know how to do it via multiple steps, and a "pseudocode" UPDATE statement, and I'm asking if there's a more efficient way. Even where I say "one-shot", it's in quotations, and I said "more of a", so it wasn't at all a hard limitation for answers. I'm not sure why you're so hung up on that one point.

Comment: @seaders Paul just would like to understand what your question is about because it is not that clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the data, try this:

```
UPDATE BetsTable b
JOIN NewTable n ON n.key = b.source
SET b.source = n.id
```

If you realy need to make the `source` column a foreign key, you will need to change it's data type first. But in that case I'm pretty sure it would be more efficient to rebuild the table.

Comment: For this, on a BetsTable with millions of rows, isn't JOIN-ing NewTable onto it going to be quite expensive, especially for millions of VARCHAR checks?  I'm always wary of joins on really big tables from past burns.

Comment: Any modern RDBMS is designed to work efficient with joins. At least when supported by proper indexes.